# Can we measure how close a vector bundle is to being trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

For a vector bundle $E$, I will denote the maximum number of linearly independent global sections of $E$ by $\eta(E)$. We have $\eta(E) \in \{0, 1, \dots, \operatorname{rank}(E)\}$ and $\eta(E) = \operatorname{rank}(E)$ if and only if $E$ is trivial - for this reason, $\eta(E)$ should be a measure of how close a given bundle is to being trivial.

There are many examples where $\eta(E) = \operatorname{rank}(E)$, for example $E = T\mathbb{R}^n$. By a fairly well known result, $\eta(TS^n) = n$ if and only if $n = 0, 1, 3,$ or $7$; more generally, $\eta(TG) = \dim G$ for any Lie group $G$. For the other values of $n$ we can say more due to the Hairy Ball Theorem. Namely, if $n$ is even, $\eta(TS^n) = 0$, and if $n$ is odd, $\eta(TS^n) \geq 1$.

> Is $\eta(E)$ a useful piece of information; in particular, does it have a name? Are there any methods to calculate $\eta(E)$?

Comment: Note, the quantity $\eta(TS^n)$ is known precisely for every $n$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_on_spheres).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Michael, read about characteristic classes. For example, the Poincaré dual of $c_k(E)$ (the $k$th Chern class of a complex bundle of rank $n$) is the cycle along which $n-k+1$ generic sections become linearly dependent. One can also deduce directly from the behavior of Chern classes and short exact sequences of bundles, if there is a trivial subbundle of rank $k$, all Chern classes $c_j(E)=0$ for $j>n-k$. There are analogous statements for Stiefel-Whitney and Pontryagin classes of real bundles.

Comment: Thanks Ted. It will take me a while to digest this. The first reference that comes to mind is the book by Milnor and Stasheff. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: Griffiths and Harris will help you out with a more curvature-oriented approach. Chern's original paper, integrating polynomials in Chern forms over Schubert cycles in Grassmannians is lovely. I can also send you some notes from courses I've taught, if you'd like.

Comment: By Chern's original paper, do you mean *Characteristic classes of Hermitian Manifolds*? I'd very much appreciate those notes.

Comment: Michael, yes, that's the paper. I will have to send you (unfortunately) handwritten notes from school, so it'll be tomorrow. You may remove the comment, though.

Comment: No worries, there's no rush. Thanks again.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that characteristic classes allow you to bound $\eta$, but generally don't allow you to compute it directly.  The relationship is the following.  For a rank $k$ complex bundle over $M^n$, if there are $l$ independent sections, then $c_{i} = 0$ for any $i>\max\{n, k-l\}$.  A similar fact holds for real bundles using Pontryagin or Stiefel-Whitney classes.  Very often, the bounds are not sharp.  For example, any odd sphere other than $S^1$ or $S^3$ has vanishing Pontrygain and Stiefel-Whitney classes, but is never parallelizable.

Comment: Well said, thanks, @Jason.